# POST cURL request to REST API sending

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying for a while now to call a REST API, but still with no luck.

I've tested the connection, propreties and credentials with [WizTools](http://www.wiztools.org/), so I'm 100% all the data is correct and working. Only when I try to connect to the API using custom PHP, things go wrong.

I use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) for debugging and all I see is a request to the local path of the file with the code. For some reason, the snippet isn't calling the REST endpoint... I would like to know how does it come and what do I do wrong...

The code is hosted local (`dev.testing.com`).
At first sight, I would think the code below is correct, so I'm wondering why I get a `GET http://dev.testing.com/talent.php HTTP/1.1` result in Fiddler, while I should get a `POST https://api.some_url.com/package/REST/service/criteria?api_key=my_Key HTTP/1.1`..

```
<?php
       // Set all the data
       $service_url = "https://api.some_url.com/package/REST/service/criteria?api_key=my_Key";
       $service_user = 'iiii_My_Username:text:FO';
       $service_pass = 'password';

       // Initialize the cURL
       $ch = curl_init($service_url);

       // Set service authentication
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$service_user}:{$service_pass}");

       // Composing the HTTP headers     
       $body = "<searchCriteriaSorting></searchCriteriaSorting>";

       $headers = array();
       $headers[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
       $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8';

       // Set the cURL options
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

       //WARNING: this would prevent curl from detecting a 'man in the middle' attack
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

       // Execute the cURL
       $data = curl_exec($ch);

       // Print the result
       echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Use need to add CURL PROXY for  Fiddler to capture the request ... also output curl_error($ch) ... then i can help you

Comment: `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` seems to be empty and why do you need a `CURL PROXY` for Fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy server and listens to connection on port 8888 .. it work by default with browser ... but for it to work with tour CURL PHP code you need  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "localhost:8888"); then you would be able to see such traffic

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but still the same result :( I've added this line (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "localhost:8888");`) to my code, but I still get the same result in Fiddler

Comment: Since you are getting empty error ... i can really help you form here ... because of limited information ... i wish you had an error you can give me

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide you with?

Comment: demo url ... so that i can simulate the test myself ....

Comment: i got the same issue any solution??